# LINQ Query Help!

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Can someone hep me converting the following SQL query into LINQ?

```
select
    convert(varchar(10),date,110) as 'Date',
    max(users) as 'Maximum Number of Users', 
    max(transactions) as 'Maximum Number of Transactions'
from
    stats
where
    datepart(Year, Date) = '2010'
group by
    convert(varchar(10),date,110) 
order by
    convert(varchar(10),date,110)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from the limited information you've provided but this might do the job:

```
var results = from stat in db.Stats
              group stat by stat.Date.Date into statGroup
              orderby statGroup.Key
              select new
              {
                Date = statGroup.Key,
                MaximumNumberOfUsers = statGroup.Max(c => c.Users),
                MaximumNumberOfTransactions = statGroup.Max(c => c.Transactions)
              };
```

Comment: DateTime.ToString() isn't supported in L2E. But I don't think it's really needed here anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I ran this query in Linqpad and got this error: Method "System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL". The Date field has both date and time. I want to groupby only by date,not by time. I am not sure how it can be done.

Comment: Does the edited version work (use the Date property instead of the ToString method)?  Sorry, I have no way to test this right now.

Comment: As Craig said, it worked without ToString. I made a small change in the Select to display Date only: 

Stats 

.GroupBy (s => s.Date.Date) 

.OrderBy (g => g.Key) 

.Select ( g => new { 

Date = g.Key.Date.ToShortDateString(), 

MaximumNumberOfUsers = g.Max (c => c.Users), 

MaximumNumberOfTransactions = g.Max (c => c.Transactions) } ); 

THANK YOU Daniel and Craig for your help! I really appreciate it.